# Display two dashes in rst file

Tags: restructuredtext

I write an rst file and plan to display the following:

command -abc --efg

I have tried several way to escape the dash when two dashes are together, but i cannot get what I want in the compiled doc. Here are a few things I have tried:

```
command -abc --efg
command -abc \--efg
command -abc -\-efg
command -abc \-\-efg
command -abc \--\--efg
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your version of Sphinx, you either have [`html_use_smartypants=True`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_use_smartypants) (Sphinx < 1.6.6) or [`smartquotes=True`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-smartquotes) (Sphinx ≥ 1.6.6). If you omit either setting from your `conf.py` or when invoking `sphinx-build`, then the default value of `True` will be in effect, converting a double-dash "`--`" into a typographical en-dash "–". See [Smart Quotes for Docutils, Description](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/smartquotes.html#description) for all conversions.

You could escape each character in the double-dash, but that is ugly markup, and the display is not distinguishable from inline text.

```
command -abc \\-\\-efg
```

To display the command inline, surround it with double ticks.  The display is distinguishable as a command.

```
Enter the command ``command -abc --efg`` to do stuff.
```

To display the command in a separate block of text, use `.. code-block::`.

```
.. code-block:: bash

    command -abc --efg
```

Rendered display of above examples:

[image: Rendered display of above examples]